# HTML comment conventions

Tags: naming-conventions, comment-conventions, html

I need to use HTML comments to store specific data, but I don't want use comment schemes that already exist, as generated by programs like **Dreamweaver** `<!-- #BeginLibraryItem "/File.lbi" -->` or **Frontpage**.

How do I know what comment scheme would be least problematic, or at least not look like other existing comment conventions?

***PS:*** I'm told a double hypen "--" in comments sometimes breaks rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least `<!-- -->` to have a comment, and yes, you should avoid having "--" in the middle of the comment; the "--" are the actual comment delimiters. Other than that, you can just prefix it with any string and I think you'll be good -- e.g., `<!--JEREMY_RUDD: -->`.

However, storing data in comments sounds like a suboptimal idea. Can you elaborate on this? Have you considered whether, say, something like JSON might not be more appropriate?

Comment: I'll second the "suboptimal idea" comment. Comments are intended to be ignored - anything else is a hack, and opens you up to problems with other tools (such as Dreamweaver) that rely on similar hacks...

Answer (score 0):

I've started a standard, inspired by JSDoc and Javadoc: [HTMLDoc](http://usehtmldoc.org/).